# Is there a way to set the root path for ES6 imports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json, es6-modules

I have a website whose .js files handle imports by doing `import {Foobar} from /path/to/foobar.js`, where the import path starts with a slash.

I want to run this same JS on the server using node.js. Of course, the imports fail because the root path for the website does not correspond to the root directory for the server.

Do I have to change all the import statements? Or is there some setting (perhaps in package.json) where I can tell the module loader that `/` corresponds to a particular directory?

Comment: @codemirror How does base href help with Node.js?

Comment: Something like base href should help, w3schools.com/tags/att_base_href.asp

Comment: Node.js has hooks you can use to override the default resolution algorithms for ES Modules. More in [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html)

Comment: Yes, you have to change the imports declarations. You can't just serve your source files and make them work despite pointing to the wrong path on your website. Use a build tool (transpiler/bundler), they can do this.

Answer (score -2):

var absolute_path = __dirname;

So far, I've only seen the root directory be "/app"